# Click Background #FFFF00 - yellow

Tags: background, click, pyautogui, anaconda3

I would like to click on screen when the background is yellow (background = #FFFF00), how i could click?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a image of the yellow background and store it as yellow_background.png.

```
import pyautogui, time, cv2
    
time.sleep(5)
    
coord = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('yellow_backgrond.png', grayscale=True, confidence=0.7)

if coord != None:
    pyautogui.click(coord[0],coord[1])
```

Get the coordinates with the locateCenterOnScreen function and store this in a variabel "coord". Then you can use the variabel to click on the location where the yellow backgrond is located.

Comment: Tks!! But The coordinates it isn't The same all The time. How i could know where is The yellow background?

Comment: I update my post with a new sulotion. Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Still not working. =(. I'm trying to test other ththingsbut i still cant click on yellow Box on my site.